# Are enemies aware of Kled's ultimate being activated?

Tags: league-of-legends

Yesterday, I played Kled for the first time and found myself wondering if enemies were aware when I activated his ultimate/R (Chaaaaaaaarge!!!).  It makes a lot of noise on the players end.  I know Sivir's ultimate makes a noise on players end and also enemies end and am curious if this might be the same.
Similarly, there are spells where a visual effect is present when a spell is cast and incoming (think Xerath).
Does the enemy have any warning it's coming?

(patch 6.17 if it matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it makes a huge sound and some sort of drum roll sound effect when activated. Cue for you to run as fast as you can.

However it doesn't have any sort of visual warning so it may be confusing as to who Kled is charging towards.

Comment: Additionally so if you have a Kled on your team in blinds.

Comment: @BritishFerret the sounds for allied kled and enemy kled ult activation are different. Slightly. can get extremely confusing at times yea.

Comment: It's a lot like a Sion ult - you can hear the ult activation, but you don't know from where he is coming.

Comment: Sion ult scared the bejeesus out of me whenever it was activated back when it was new